# Maven repository issue

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml, nexus

Maven tries to download packages/dependencies from localhost on port 8081. This nexus url takeover is unwanted and has not happend to me before.

After running the usual `mvn clean install` this happens:

```
Downloading:
http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0/plexus-io-1.0.jar
Downloading: 
http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus- archiver/1.0/plexus-archiver-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.enonic.kurs:my-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/xx yy/Documents/Enonic plugins/project/project/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.enonic.cms.tools:maven-cms-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved
```

All the times before dependencies have been downloaded from specified repositories. Repository in my pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>enonic</id>
        <name>Enonic Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.enonic.com/maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.enonic.cms</groupId>
        <artifactId>cms-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   .........
   ---------
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.enonic.cms.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cms-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**EDIT: I think I've found the problem**, but no solution to it yet.
Inside the build plugin `com.enonic.cms.tools:maven-cms-plugin` there are dependencies to `plexus-utils`, `plexus-io` and `plexus-archiver` and it looks like there are connection problems to these, which forces local repository lookup.

Debug info:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] com.enonic.cms.tools:maven-cms-plugin:jar:1.0.0:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:compile 
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-osgi:jar:0.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       biz.aQute:bndlib:jar:0.0.203:compile
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /Users/geir nygard/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar from [nexus (http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /Users/geir nygard/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0/plexus-archiver-1.0.jar from [nexus (http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /Users/geir nygard/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0/plexus-io-1.0.jar from [nexus (http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public, releases+snapshots)]
```

**Settings.xml:**

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
      <!--make the profile active all the time -->
      <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

After editing `settings.xml` changing `mirrorOf` contents to  `*,!enonic` I get this error:

```
ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin' from the repositories [local (/Users/xx yy/.m2/repository), enonic (http://repo.enonic.com/maven), nexus (http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of yourr settings xml file is exactly why arbitary repository lookup is being redirected into local nexus repo

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

The problem occur because the specified artifact doesn't exist on your local nexus repository. Either remove this section from settings xml, or fix your local repository such that it's mirroring http://repo.enonic.com/maven properly

Note that you can also mirror everything except enonic by specifying

```
<mirrorOf>*,!enonic</mirrorOf>
```

Also looking further down your settings.xml I see some section that doesn't make sense, does `http://central` resolve at all? Might as well remove this

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://central</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://central</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

I recommend you review Maven basics on the manual page: http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html

Comment: In my browser I can connect to the url.. To my knowledge there hasn't been any changes since last time it worked. The problem is that maven tries to use local repository? Should I comment out something in settings.xml?

Comment: I updated my post with more info on the problem. Have some lookup issues with dependencies in my <build> plugin (maven-cms-plugin)

Comment: Please show what's your repository mirror settings on `~/.m2/settings.xml` or `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`

Comment: Done, posted at the bottom.

Comment: Now I got a new error: `ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin' from the repositories [local (/Users/geir nygard/.m2/repository), enonic (http://repo.enonic.com/maven), nexus (http://192.168.10.46:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @gorn further down your settings.xml there are more section that doesn't make sense. Please see my updated answer. I suggest you read Maven manual so you understand what those settings mean

Comment: I copied over a default settings.xml and it fixed my issues.